# Different Granger causality results in Matlab versus R

Tags: r, matlab, granger-causality

I'm trying to test for Granger causality of two data sets A and B. The time series length is 106.

First I used Matlab function [`granger_cause`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25467-granger-causality-test) and the results are as follow:

```
 [F,c_v]=granger_cause(a,b,0.05,7)
F =
    6.2566
c_v =
    2.1955
```

Then I used R function [`granger.test`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/MSBVAR/docs/granger.test) in the package MSBVAR to do the same thing:

```
    granger.test(c,7)
       F-statistic   p-value
b -> a   0.9553480 0.4691375
a -> b   0.9224725 0.4934965
```

Here `c` is the combination of column vectors `a` and `b`.

Clearly, the first function specifies the $\alpha$ level and outputs the critical value of the $F$-test, while the second gives the $p$-value and lets user determine the $\alpha$ level.

What I don't understand is why these two functions give me different $F$-values? Is there anything I need to be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think this question will be impossible to answer without one. Note also that questions about software / code are typically off topic here, & this Q may be also.

Comment: Jingyu, I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 2):

In the Matlab function `granger_cause`, the lag length is selected using BIC and the last argument to the function is the *maximum* lag to be considered.

In the R function `granger.test`, the *exact* lag length is supplied by the second argument.

It may be the case that in your application you actually ended up having different lag lenghts (since in Matlab some other lag than 7 was selected by BIC), and therefore you got different results.